# Do summation if factor does not depend on index

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

I have the following sums $$\sum _{j=0}^{n-1} \left(\sum _{c=1}^K \left(\sum _{b=1}^K m[b]^2\right)\right)$$ or $$\sum _{j=0}^{n-1} \left(\sum _{c=1}^K \text{$ n$}[c]\right)$$
where $m[b]$ and $n[c]$ are undefined vectors. As you can see, in the first case the two summations are just summed on 1, since the only index in $m$ is $b$ and similar for the second one. What I would like mathematica to do is to simplify such sums like $$Kn\sum_{b=1}^K m[b]^2$$ and $$n\sum_{c=1}^K n[c]$$ for the second one. How could I do it in full generality?

## Code

I have some user defined functions which I'm using

```
a3 = Attributes[Sum];
Unprotect[Sum];
ClearAttributes[Sum, a3];
Attributes[Sum];
Sum[f_ g_, i_] := f Sum[g, i] /; FreeQ[f, i[[1]]]
SetAttributes[Sum, a3];

SumExpand[exp_] := 
  exp /. Sum[c_, {i_, a_, b_}] :> 
    Distribute[Sum[ExpandAll[c], {i, a, b}]];

NewSum[exp_, {i_, i0_, n_}] := SumExpand[Sum[exp, {i, i0, n}]];
```

And

```
c2[x_] := Sign[Coefficient[x, s]] (x - \[Omega])^2;
```

The calculation which gives the factors cited above, plus many others, is the following

```
cc[1] = NewSum[
   NewSum[
    NewSum[
     NewSum[
      c2[j \[Tau]A + l \[Tau]B + m[b] + n[c] + 2 s], {b, 1, K} ], {c, 
      1, K}], {j, 0, n - 1}], {l, 0, 2}] + 
  NewSum[
   NewSum[
    NewSum[
     NewSum[
      c2[j \[Tau]A + l \[Tau]B + m[a] + n[c] + s], {a, 1, Nf} ], {c, 
      1, K}], {j, 0, n - 1}], {l, 0, 2}] + 
  NewSum[
   NewSum[
    NewSum[
     NewSum[c2[j \[Tau]A + l \[Tau]B + m[a] + n[d]], {a, 1, Nf} ], {b,
       1, Nf}], {j, 0, n - 1}], {l, 0, 2}]
```

The factos: $s,\omega, Nf, K, n$ are constants and

```
\[Tau]A = (2 \[Omega])/(n + 1);
\[Tau]B = (n \[Omega])/(n + 1);
```

these are $\tau_A, \tau_B$.

Comment: @MarcoB Well the code is a little bit cumbersome, but I'm adding it now

Comment: @MarcoB of course!

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: A quick-and-dirty redefinition of `Sum` (which might be a little dangerous!) could involve adding the following two lines after your factoring definition: `Sum[expr_, {i_, n0_, n1_}] := (n1 - n0 + 1) expr /; FreeQ[expr, i];
Sum[expr_, iter0___, {i_, n0_, n1_}, iter1___] := 
 Sum[(n1 - n0 + 1) expr, iter0, iter1] /; FreeQ[{expr, iter1}, i]`. (Note that later iterators (`iter1`) are actually the "inner" iterators, perhaps counterintuitively.) There are of course cases that this doesn't catch, but it seems to work for your expression...!